# Foreach go up by 1 php

Tags: php, foreach

I want to read out the information of some access points. These access points are numberd where in the code at this moment [0] stand has to go up by 1 in the loop. then the loop can run again and read out the information of the second AC and so on.

```
$name      = $ac0->result[0]->name;
$status    = $ac0->result[0]->status;
$uptime    = $ac0->result[0]->uptime;
$last_seen = $ac0->result[0]->last_seen;
```

All code

```
foreach ($ac0->result as $key => $value) { 
    $name0 = $ac0->result[0]->name; 
    $status0 = $ac0->result[0]->status; 
    $uptime0 = $ac0->result[0]->uptime; 
    $last_seen0 = $ac0->result[0]->last_seen; 
}
```

Comment: you want to iterate over the `$ac0->result` array?

Comment: yes indeed I want to iterate over the     result

Comment: `foreach ($ac0->result as $key => $value)`?

Comment: treyBake keep seeing the [0] but i want to see the [1], [2], [3], [4] till 7

Comment: Show us what you have coded. As it does not sound like you did as @treyBake suggested

Comment: Show your complete code and expected result.

Comment: foreach ($ac0->result as $key => $value) {
            $name0 = $ac0->result[0]->name;
            $status0 = $ac0->result[0]->status;
            $uptime0 = $ac0->result[0]->uptime;
            $last_seen0 = $ac0->result[0]->last_seen;
        }

Comment: you need to access the array by loop key in your code, `$ac0->result[$key]`, but it's pretty much pointless since your intended var is already in `$value`, use @RiggsFolly answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the loop at the `$ac0->result` and then all the properties will be found in the `$obj` or whatever you like to call it in the foreach loop

```
foreach ($ac0->result as $idx => $obj) {
    echo "From Array $idx <br>";
    echo $obj->name . "<br>";
    echo $obj->status . "<br>";
    // etc
}
```

Comment: but does it count up the $idx by 1?

Comment: All loop in ALL Languages start at the beginning and go up by One unless otherwise stipulated