# Problem to convert unix time to human time

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a online controller where i want to know the uptime and last seen of my access points. for this i use the epoch convert methode to convert unix time to human readable time.

this is the code i use

```
// getting controller ap info //

    $name=$status=$uptime=$last_seen=[];
foreach ($ligowave->result as $index => $obj) {
    $name[]      = $obj->name;
    $status[]    = $obj->status;
    $uptime[]    = $obj->uptime;
    $last_seen[] = $obj->last_seen;
}


// time settings //

$epoch = $uptime;
$uptimetime = (new DateTime("@$epoch"))->format(' H:i:s');

$epoch = $last_seen;
$lastseendate = (new DateTime("@$epoch"))->SetTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'))->format(' d-m-Y H:i:s');

if ($status == "up") {
    echo $name;
    echo " is up, ";
    echo "uptime is:" . $uptimetime;
} else {
    echo $name;
    echo " is down, ";
    echo "device is last seen:" . $lastseendate;
}
return array($name, $status, $epoch, $uptimetime, $lastseendate);
}
```

the error i am getting is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed
>   to parse time string (@Array) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character

Comment: what's being overwritten? What are you doing outside the loop? Logical guessing would suggest you want `$var[]` .. but how things actually are can be different to logic

Comment: I have a feeling this was already asked before on SO(probably yesterday) and got an accepted answer too.

Comment: Is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428779/foreach-go-up-by-1-php) @vivek_23?

Comment: @quickSwap Yes.

Comment: yes but now i am getting or the first one or the last one

Comment: yesterday i was getting none

Comment: @mitch I meant for you to update the question with the code related to the `DateTime` issue and the error message you're receiving.

Comment: @fyrye updated!

Comment: @mitch Please consider updating your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Outside of the issue with `DateTime` It is not clear what you are intending to have happen with your `foreach`, `echo`, and `return`. It would helpful to provide an example of your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is caused by defining `$uptime[]` as an array of values, resulting in `$epoch = $uptime` containing an array of timestamp strings. When `DateTime()` expects a single `string` value.

To resolve the issue you need to move the `DateTime` calls inside of the `foreach` iteration.

The other issue, as mentioned in the answer provided by Martin, is that you are not handling exceptions within your code. If `uptime` or `last_seen` is not of an expected value that is being supplied to the `DateTime` constructor, an exception will be thrown.

To handle the exceptions you can use a`try/catch` block in order to handle an issue that arises in your code. Exceptions are meant to point you to fatal errors in your code so that you can resolve or verify them programmatically and typically should not be ignored by using `try/catch`. For more details please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish with your code. It appears you are wanting to `echo` and `return` *all* of the values from `$ligowave->result`. I made the appropriate changes below to reflect what I surmise are your intentions. Along with some minor simplifications.

Please clarify what you are wanting to `return` and `echo` and I will adjust my answer.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/O0nS6

```
   //...

    // getting controller ap info //

        $values = [];
        foreach ($ligowave->result as $index => $obj) {
            //convert the unix timestamps to DateTime objects
            $uptime = (new DateTime('@' . $obj->uptime));
            $last_seen = (new DateTime('@' . $obj->last_seen))->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

            //store the return values into an array
            $values[] = $value = [
                'name' => $obj->name,
                'status' => $obj->status,
                'uptimetime' => $uptime->format('H:i:s'),
                'lastseendate' => $last_seen->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')
            ];

            //output each of the statuses
            printf('%s is %s, ', $obj->name, $obj->status);
            if ('up' === $obj->status) {
                echo 'uptime is: ' . $value['uptimetime'];
            } else {
                echo 'device is last seen: ' . $value['lastseendate'];
            }
        }

        return $values;
}
```

**Result:**

```
foo is up, uptime is: 10:20:54
bar is down, device is last seen: 01-06-2019 08:22:30
```

**Returns:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'foo',
    'status' => 'up',
    'uptimetime' => '10:20:54',
    'lastseendate' => '05-06-2019 11:16:21',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'bar',
    'status' => 'down',
    'uptimetime' => '10:20:54',
    'lastseendate' => '01-06-2019 08:22:30',
  ),
)
```

---

It also appears that you are using a 24 hour time, to represent a duration.
If so you will need to use a `DateInterval` instead of `DateTime`, by using [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) from an appropriate timeframe. For more details please see https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Assuming `uptime` is the started time and `last_seen` is the current run time, you can use `$uptime->diff($last_seen)`, to retrieve the time that elapsed between `uptime` to `last_seen` (duration), instead of the 24 hour time value of `uptime`. Otherwise you can use `$uptime->diff(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')))`, to use the current date time.

One caveat, is that the hours of `DateInterval` are non cumulative, meaning you would need to add the days in some manner. I have used the most accurate of `%a` as opposed to adding on to the hours with `days * 24`

### Example: https://3v4l.org/LHdqL

```
//...

$uptime = (new DateTime('@' . $obj->uptime))->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$last_seen = (new DateTime('@' . $obj->last_seen))->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
$values[] = $value = [
    'name' => $obj->name,
    'status' => $obj->status,
    'lastseendate' => $last_seen->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
    'uptimetime' => $uptime->diff($last_seen)->format('%a.%H:%I:%S'), //DD.HH:MM:SS
];

//...
```

**Result:**

```
foo is up, uptime is: 12.22:48:26
```

Comment: @Martin Thanks, It's not certain that handling exceptions intended, so I focused on the cause of the exception, rather than on handling them, but I have updated to include the note about the exclusion of exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Please Note:
>
> This answer is **only** about resolving the specific PHP error as stated on the question. For a wider answer about how to effectively write code to iterate over arrays please see [Fyrye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56463626/3536236).

The error you are receiving is:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@Array) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character

## What is actually wrong, and why?

**1)** 
You have an uncaught Exception, which throws a fatal error due to being, er, uncaught. Exceptions are central to object programming and should be [**researched and implemented**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in your PHP scripts.

**2)**
Why do you have an Exception in the first place? The error states the exception is caused by "Failed to parse time string (@Array)". So you are trying to give the `DateTime` object an *array* when it expects a *string*. It would help you to [**Read the PHP DateTime `__construct` Manual Page**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

**3)**
Further, and more specifically the `@` character is unexpected; which means it should not be there. This character is only valid when followed by *timestamp* integer values in *string* format.

Because the array is output as a *string* (i.e in quotes) the end result is "@Array" and so the `@` is taken literally by `DateTime`; but of course this character is not expected by DateTime in any non-numeric incoming time string. This is the root cause of your fatal error here.

While PHP does employ loose typecasting to some extent, wrapping an array `$var` in quotes is far *too* loose and so the array simply outputs "Array" and issues a corresponding PHP Notice:

> **Notice**: Array to string conversion in .....

For a valid list of correct DateTime string formats to give the object you can [**view this page from the PHP Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

**4)**
I do not see why you need those outer brackets?

## So, how should this be done?

Reading the issues in reverse order from 4 to 1; the correct way of resolving this specific error is:

- Wrap the attempt into a try/catch block to avoid these fatal errors.
- Ensure that the value given to the `DateTime` object is a *string*
- Remove unnecessary and invalid characters from that string.

So:

```
$epoch = $uptime;

try{ 
     /***
      * Uptime appears to be a numeric array of time string values 
      * Therefore go for the first one. 
      * You may want to wrap this code in a loop to catch each one.  
      ***/
     $uptimeTime = new DateTime("@".(string)$epoch[0]);
}
catch (Exception $ex){
    /***
     * If you wish to ignore these errors simply leave this block empty
     ***/
    error_log("There was a problem on line ".__LINE__."! ".print_r($ex));
}
/***
 * By default UTC timestamps are not zoned.   
 ***/
// $uptimeTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

$uptimeTimeOutput = $uptimeTime->format('H:i:s');
/***
 * $uptimeTimeOutput is the correctly formatted date from $epoch[0]
 ***/
 print $uptimeTimeOutput;
```

I hope with the information given above your able to correct the second `DateTime` instantiation code (ie the `new DateTime` line) yourself. `:-)`

## TL;DR

Please read the PHP Manual and allow it to inform your coding choices.

Comment: From the code the OOP shows, `$epoch` is an Array of valid values. If these values are timestamp `int`s, yes, that's not going to work, I have personally found that `DateTime` construct to be far less flexible than other DateTime methods. Thanks!

Comment: Just so that you are aware, the author has been [having issues with understanding array iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428779/foreach-go-up-by-1-php). The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56461780/1) was resolved by now deleted answers, which lead to issues with the array of timestamps the OP is encountering now.

Comment: @fyrye thanks again. I saw your post about iteration over the array and that's a good explanation, I did not want to steamroller over your answer, but wanted to actually claify and clear up the specific error (only) as displayed on the question. Many posts on SO are a domino effect of OP issues.....

Comment: @fyrye I have heavily revised my answer. I also removed the bit about timezones. Cheers